# Playing HTML5 Audio using audio.js requires three taps on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio, audiojs

On iOS and desktop I don't have problems playing my HTML5 audio with audio.js – everything works fine. But with Android the play-button needs three taps to play!

I've also written a issue about this on audio.js' github: https://github.com/kolber/audiojs/issues/177

REPRO:

1. go to http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ on a Android phone (I tested with Xperia Z1/Android 4.4.2)
2. expected the play/pause button to be in play state initally, but is in loading state
3. clicking play makes the button go into play state
4. clicking again sets the button into loading state
5. clicking again sets the button into playing state, and this time finally plays the audio!

How can I make it play with only one tap/click??

Comment: Maybe you have slower internet connection with the phone and it needs to load longer before you can play audio?

Comment: Not really slow, 50mbit. Just upgraded to android 4.4.4 and now it works as it should! But now I can't test on older android anymore (<4.4.2).. hm..can anyone else reproduce the problem?